# Why is there a 14-year difference between the submission date of this arXiv paper and the date in the paper text?

Tags: publications, arxiv

I am so confused. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9905066) is listed as having been submitted in 1999, but the date below the author's names inside the PDF is 2013.

What is the meaning of each date?

Comment: Now it states 2018.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The LaTex source code contains the `\date{\today}` command, which inserts the current date *at the time of compilation*. That is, the PDF is probably last regenerated in 2013. The arXiv submission history gives a more reliable date.

Comment: Yes, this is one annoying feature of current arXiv. I wish they could do the obvious thing (viz., redefining \today).